# What is the "context" in a function

Tags: haskell, monads

I  am trying to get more familiar with Haskell(Functor,Monad). So i am trying to understand what's happening in the below example

```
 sequence:: [f a] -> f [a]
 let list =  [(+2), (*6)]
 let y =  sequence  list
```

What is the "f" in (+2) and the "value" of y ?

Comment: The `f` should have a constraint: `Monad f`. Here it is an "arrow", so `f ~ (->) b`.

Comment: Your title asks about context, but your question content says otherwise. What's your actual question?

Comment: @AJFarmar  What is the  "value" of y ?

Comment: @AJFarmar I think they meant the "value in context" metaphor of functorial values.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `sequenceA` is:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

(I'm using `sequenceA` because it is the more general version -- `sequence` has a more restrictive `Monad` constraint instead of the `Applicative` one -- but as far as this answer is concerned it doesn't matter much.)

Let's say your `list` has type `[Integer -> Integer]` (I'm specialising the numbers for the sake of clarity). Then `sequenceA` in `sequenceA list` specialises to:

```
[Integer -> Integer] -> (Integer -> [Integer])
```

The correspondence is easier to see if we write the interesting (for us here) type constructors in *prefix style*:

```
-- t (           f       a) ->             f ( t       a)
  [] ((->) Integer Integer) -> ((->) Integer ([] Integer))
```

The list functor, `[]`, is the traversable functor (the `t` in the signature of `sequenceA`), while `(->) Integer`, the *functions-from-`Integer`* functor, is the relevant applicative functor (the `f` in the signature), or, to use the language of your title, the relevant applicative context. For instance, in the `Integer -> [Integer]` result type, instead of having plain list of integers, you have a function from `Integer`s which produces such list.